Are $\lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty,x\infty)} (1 + 1/n)^m$ and ${\substack{n \to \infty \\m = nx}} (1 + \frac1n)^m$ correct alternative definitions of $e^x$?
I know $e^x =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac xn\right)^n$. But I'd like to use a different notation (for a video). I'm not sure if this is correct, but here it is: $e^x = \lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty,x\infty)}(1 + \frac1n)^m$.
A second option would be: $e^x = \lim_{\substack{n \to \infty \\m = nx}} (1 + \frac1n)^m$, $n, m \in \mathbb N$.
edit: $x > 0$

Why would you want to introduce a second variable, which is dependent on the first? Are you trying to show the equality by substitution $m=nx$?$$\lim_{m\to\infty}(1+x/m)^m=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^{nx}$$

I'm trying to explain logarithms from scratch in a video, and this came up.

The first option is wrong because $x \infty$ is not well-defined in this context.
The second option is correct, but the notation is non-standard. I would just write:
$$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^{nx}.$$

Your first option doesn't really make much sense since $x\infty$ is ill-defined. I guess if you interpret it like "$\operatorname{sign}(x) \cdot \infty$" you can salvage that bit of it, giving
$$
e^x = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty,\infty)} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m, & x > 0 \\
\displaystyle \lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty,0)} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m, & x = 0 \\
\displaystyle \lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty,-\infty)} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m, &x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
However, to handle the double limit here, you would require that, more cleanly,
$$
\lim_{(n,m) \to (N,M)} a_{n,m} \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=}
\underbrace{\lim_{n \to N} \lim_{m \to M} a_{n,m}=
\lim_{m \to M}  \lim_{n \to N} a_{n,m}}_{\text{this equality must hold!}}
$$
for our sequence
$$
a_{n,m} \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m
$$
with $N,M \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$.
But notice that, since $1+\frac 1 n >1$, we'd have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty}\left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \infty
= \infty
$$
while
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m
=
\lim_{m \to \infty} 1^m
= 1
$$
I imagine the other cases have similar issues, but this is enough to already show issues.

As far as
$$
e^x = \lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty,nx)} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m
$$
is concerned, this is just ... silly and unnecessary since you're forcing $m=nx$ anyways so
$$
e^x = \lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty,nx)} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^{nx}
$$
an already known equality.

edit: x > 0 (I forgot)
